# sharedpreferences after removing the values and launches appilcation again it showing values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have checkbox if i click checkbox and login then username and password is saved in sharedpreferences..and moves to FirstScreen Activity....then if i close application and relaunches again 
then the application has to move directly to FirstScrren ...this is fine for me and working well...

issue:: if i login after entering details and click on checkbox...moves to firstScrren there if i logout and it comes to LoginScreen 
by removing values in shared preferences...it also fine...but here if i press back button and open application again then it showing the values of the logged in ..(in this condition it has to be empty...)

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 EditText username,passwordField;
 Button login,registerButton;
 CheckBox check;

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String userStored;
    String passwordStored;
     boolean checked =false;
     boolean checkboxvalue;
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_File";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);



    username =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    passwordField =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);      
    check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);     

    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             if (check.isChecked()) {

                checked = true;

                settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                editor = settings.edit();                                   
                editor.putString("User_Shared", username.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("Pass_Shared", passwordField.getText().toString());                
                editor.putBoolean("Checkbox_Click", true);

                editor.commit();

                userStored = settings.getString("User_Shared",null);
                passwordStored =settings.getString("Pass_Shared", null);                     
                checkboxvalue = settings.getBoolean("Checkbox_Click", false);

                System.out.println("userStored :::" +userStored + " ::::pasword ::::" +passwordStored + ":::check" + checkboxvalue );



            }               



             Intent intent =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstScreen.class);
             startActivity(intent);


        }
    });



}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();



    if ( userStored != null  &&  ! userStored.isEmpty()) {

         username.setText(userStored);
         passwordField.setText(passwordStored);          

         Intent intent1 = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), FirstScreen.class);
         startActivity(intent1);

    }


    else{

         username.setText("");
         passwordField.setText(""); 

    }


}

}




public class FirstScreen extends Activity {


    Button logout;
    User myApplication;  
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_File";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);


  myApplication = (User) getApplicationContext();

  logout =(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);

  logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        settings =getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();   

           try {

               editor.remove("User_Shared");
               editor.remove("Pass_Shared");
               editor.remove("Checkbox_Click");

        //     editor.clear();
               editor.commit();
        }

           catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
           catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("Logout", logout);

        startActivity(intent);



    }
});



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

     moveTaskToBack(true);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is just the `TextViews` display the last values of it, as when the **Back** button pressed, the activity just resumed not recreated, so, try to set it's values on back press or before moving to `FirstScreen` activity.

**Through onBackPressed :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    LoginActivity.username.setText(""); but in this case they must be public static in the LoginActivity
    LoginActivity.passwordField.setText(""); 
    moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

**Before moving to the FirstScreen activity:**

```
  login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 .
                 .
                 .
           username.setText("");
           passwordField.setText(""); 
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstScreen.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

you can also just **override the onResume method of the Activity by that:**

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    username.setText("");
    passwordField.setText(""); 
}
```

**p.s.** whatever this helped you to figure our the problem or not, you must never pass a `null` as a default value to the `SharedPreferences` object, you have to pass `""` in the case of `Strings` (may be this is what it gives you the current behaviour), just modify it to the following:

```
 userStored = settings.getString("User_Shared","");
 passwordStored =settings.getString("Pass_Shared", "");
```

Comment: What makes you say you can never pass null as a default string value? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: @mjp66 I said " you must never" not "you can never", it's a really bad practice to give a default value as null instead of a real value

Comment: I understood what you meant, sorry for using "can" instead of "must". In this case though, defaulting to null is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @mjp66 well that's ok, I just want him to handle it if the preferences doesn't give him a value, so then he will have one which is " "

Answer (score 0):

Your preferences keys don't match: "User_Shared" in one activity and "user_StoreShared" in the other; same with "Pass_Shared" and "password_StoreShared". Those keys have to be named the same. So, in your second activity, change this:

```
editor.remove("user_StoreShared");
editor.remove("password_StoreShared");
```

to this:

```
editor.remove("User_Shared");
editor.remove("Pass_Shared");
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when you click the logout button and then exit the app, everything acts as it should upon relaunch, but when you just click the back button (without first clicking the logout button), it doesn't. This sounds like normal behaviour to me. By clicking nothing but the back button, whatever actions you have performing on your logout button don't take effect.